# ActionBar + Tab Navigation(MapView + ListView) fragments

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mapview, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm wondering how can I work with a listfragment, and at the same time, using an static linearlayout with 4 filter buttons at the top of the list. Here is the problem:

First of all, I use an Action Bar + Tab Navigation from [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) :

**QuestList extends FragmentMapActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getTabs();
}

private void getTabs() {
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
    tab1.setText("Geo");
    tab1.setTabListener(this);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab1);

    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
    tab2.setText("No Geo");
    tab2.setTabListener(this);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab2);
}

...

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (tab.getText().toString().compareTo("Geo") == 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, Map.getInstance()).commit();
    }
    else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, List.newInstance(0)).commit();     
    }
}
```

I got some problems with the MapView, but I finally fixed all of them. Now the problem is that I want something like this:

[Static LinearLayout + ListFragment](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/341/capturadepantalla201201q.png/)

**List extends ListFragment**

```
...
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    initializations();

    getQuests();

    if (gigHash.isEmpty()) {
        TextView eList = new TextView(getActivity());
        eList.setText(R.string.no_loc_gig_no_items);
        eList.setWidth(Gravity.CENTER);
    }
    else {
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            mAdapter = new NoLocGigAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.gig_noloc_row_land,gigList);
        }
        else {
            mAdapter = new NoLocGigAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.gig_noloc_row,gigList);
        }                       
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
...
```

So I'm using my own adapter and I get all my items from a service.

The problem is, doing the transaction, I can only use a fragment, and I have to show the items dinamically with my own ArrayAdapter, so I don't know how to include a part of static code into that view...

Any suggestion? I think that handle with fragments it's a little weird!

PS: At first, I thought that I could call a fragment, and this, calling a static xml within the linearlayout and a ListFragment inside, but I think I can't do this, right?